# Equivalence of Two Metrics

Tags: general-topology

I have two questions concerning equivalence of two metrics:

1. I need to prove the equivalence of two metrics on the space $(0,1]$, $d_1(x,y)=\lvert x-y\rvert$ and $d_2(x,y)=\left\lvert \frac1x-\frac1y\right\rvert$.

   By definition, one needs to find two positive constants k and K such that:
   $$\forall x,y \in (0,1],\ \ kd_1(x,y) \le d_2(x,y) \le Kd_1(x,y) $$

   $k=1$ works well but I can't find a constant $K$. For $y$ fixed and $x$ approaching $0$, $x \in (0,1]$, $K$ must increase and thus can't be a constant.
2. In the book I am learning from, the equivalence of two metrics is defined in the following way: The metrics $d$ and $D$ defined on $X$ are equivalent if there is a constant $k\ge 1$ such that for all $x,y\in X$, $d(x,y) \le kD(x,y)$ and $D(x,y) \le kd(x,y)$.

   Is this definition equivalent to the usual one, where one must find two constants ? In other words, I can't see how one can transform the one into the other.

Thanks a lot for any comment.

Comment: The existence of $k$ and $K$ is called uniform (or strong) equivalence. Equivalence of metrics means they generate the same topology. That does not imply uniform equivalence. For example $d_1(x,y)=|x-y|$ and $d_2(x,y)=\min (1,d_1(x,y))$ are equivalent metrics on $\mathbb R,$  but not uniformly equivalent

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{abs}[1]{\left\lvert{#1}\right\rvert}$
1. The two metrics are not (*strongly*) equivalent. In fact (as you've noticed), $$\sup_{x\ne y\in (0,1]}\frac{d_2(x,y)}{d_1(x,y)}=\sup_{x\ne y\in(0,1]}\frac{1}{xy}=+\infty$$
However, they are *weakly* equivalent, id est, they induce the same topology. You've already proved that $id:((0,1],d_2)\to ((0,1],d_1)$ is Lipschitz  continuous. To prove that it is a homeomorphism, you must prove that $$id:((0,1],d_1)\to((0,1],d_2)$$ is continuous. But this is tantamount to saying that, if $\lvert x_n-y\rvert\to 0$ with $x_n,y>0$, then  $\abs{\frac1{x_n}-\frac1y}\to 0$; which is the well known fact that $\frac1x$ is a continuous map $(0,1]\to [1,\infty)$.
2. The one with two constants $m,M$ satisfies your condition for $k=\max\left\{1,\frac1m,M\right\}$. Yours satisfies the $m$-$M$ one for $M=k$ and $m=\frac1k$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Of the two (weakly) equivalent metrics only the second one should be a complete one in (0,1]. Can you give me a sugestion on how to approach this last question ? Thanks.

Comment: @user249018 The map $x\mapsto \frac1x$ is a bijective isometry $((0,1],d_2)\to ([1,\infty),\lvert \bullet\rvert)$ and the latter is complete.

Comment: @G.Sassatelli in the part when you prove that $((0,1],d_1)\to((0,1],d_2)$ is continuous, it seems to me like you're showing that if $d_2(x_n,y)\to d_2(x,y)$, then $d_1(x_n,y)\to d_1(x,y)$. Should you be proving the converse instead?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Edited, thank you.